# Difference between <jsp-attribute name="reloadEnabled" value="true"/> and <enable-reloading value="true"/> in ibm-web-ext.xml for WebSphere

Tags: java, xml, jsp, websphere

Several jsp-attribute entries seem to have similar entries later in the ibm-web-ext.xml file for WebSphere. For example, `<jsp-attribute name="reloadInterval" value="5"/>` and `<reload-interval value="5"/>` as well as the one mentioned in the title (`<jsp-attribute name="reloadEnabled" value="true"/>` and `<enable-reloading value="true"/>`). Are they both required to set the reloading on? Or do they control different things? https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSAW57_7.0.0/com.ibm.websphere.nd.doc/info/ae/ae/rweb_jspreloading.html talks about the jsp-attribute entries, but doesn't seem to explain the similar non-jsp-attribute entries.

Here's an example file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-ext
    xmlns="http://websphere.ibm.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://websphere.ibm.com/xml/ns/javaee http://websphere.ibm.com/xml/ns/javaee/ibm-web-ext_1_0.xsd"
    version="1.0">

   <jsp-attribute name="trackDependencies" value="true" />
   <jsp-attribute name="disableJspRuntimeCompilation" value="true" />

   <!-- Are these two lines the same thing as....  --> 
   <jsp-attribute name="reloadEnabled" value="true"/>
   <jsp-attribute name="reloadInterval" value="5"/>

   <auto-encode-requests value="false"/>
   <auto-encode-responses value="false"/>
   <enable-directory-browsing value="false"/>
   <enable-file-serving value="false"/>
   <pre-compile-jsps value="false"/>

   <!-- .... these two lines? -->
   <enable-reloading value="true"/>
   <reload-interval value="5"/>

   <enable-serving-servlets-by-class-name value="false" />  
</web-ext>
```

Answer (score 2):

The JSP attributes named reloadEnabled and reloadInterval are WebSphere web application extensions (bindings) that enable JSP class reloading (https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSAW57_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.nd.doc/ae/uweb_jspreload.html). When reloadEnabled is true the server's webcontainer will reload an application's JSP files that have updated within the specified reloadInterval.

The enable-reloading and reload-interval attributes are WebSphere Enterprise Java Bean (EJB) and web application extensions that enable a server to dynamically reload (https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSAW57_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.nd.doc/ae/trun_app_hotupgrade.html) an EJB or web application module upon detecting an update to its deployment.  Such updates would include a servlet class, for example.  When enable-reloading is true in a web application, the server's classloading runtime will poll for changes to the web application deployment over the specified reload-interval and reload the web module whenever a change is detected.

The two pairs of attributes control different application reloading behaviors, and neither pair interacts with the other -- for example, you need not enable JSP reloading to also enable dynamic reloading.

The interaction of all reloading attributes is described in topic "Class loading and update detection settings" of the WebSphere Application Server Knowledge Center (https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SS7K4U_7.0.0/com.ibm.websphere.nd.multiplatform.doc/info/ae/ae/urun_rapp_classload.html).

Regarding the enablement of dynamic reloading: avoid setting the enable-reload attribute to true within EJB and web application extensions. This "original" control scheme proved problematic in the field and was later superseded by new controls added to the application deployment within the cell configuration. In the administrative console these new controls are labeled "Override class reloading settings for Web and EJB modules" and "Polling interval for updated files (seconds)". When the override is enabled the server will ignore the enable-reload and reload-interval attributes in the application extensions, and instead, will poll for changes to all application modules over the specific polling interval. Enabling the override and setting the polling interval to zero (0) will disable dynamic reloading for the application on the application server. These new controls are also documented in section "Class loading attributes and update detection settings"

Use these extensions for developing applications. JSP reloading can be very effective for verifying rapid changes to deployed JSP files. Dynamic reloading can be effective when hot deploying simple changes to applications; but for complex updates, save time by manually restarting the entire application instead of relying on dynamic reloading to detect changes.

Comment: To piggyback on Dave's last paragraph regarding the use case, I'd note that reloading is NOT recommended for production environments, because any detected change to a file in the application (including a transient failure to read a file, perhaps if it was on a networked file system), would trigger an application/module restart and leave the application unavailable during the time of the restart.

Comment: Thanks Dave and Jarid - that clears it up for me perfectly.